# How do I get ribbons in Pokemon Vortex?

Tags: pokemon-vortex

Ribbons in [pokemon vortex](http://pokemonvortex.org) are for legendary pokemon. How do you get them?

I have found all the gyms and elite 4s.

Comment: You should ask them about it. They have a twitter, facebook, discord, and forums.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in Vortex [wiki](http://pokevortex.wikia.com/wiki/Features) and saw this:

> Achievements are now available through certain milestones of your
>   account. You will receive a ribbon added to your in-game profile for
>   each achievement you complete.

and [here](http://forums.pokemonvortex.org/index.php?s=cddb8ed83e94010f5d8b0e4283ce86d8&showtopic=8&st=0) is a topic that start talking about the Ribbons on Pokemon Vortex.

At page 2 Lekroty made the first citation of ribbons

> Maybe an achievement system of some sort would be interesting. For
>   example you get a ribbon if you beat all of the elite 4 members a
>   certain amount of time, or you get another one when your average or
>   total exp reaches a certain amount, etc. I think you get the idea. It
>   might even help to stop people from using training accounts, since you
>   have to beat the "offically" coded trainers and unlock something (even
>   if its only a ribbon that gives nothing). So, what do you think?

Some [side quests](http://pokevortex.wikia.com/wiki/Side_Quests) also give Ribbons to you